# Bootstrap navbar vertical to horizontal or vise-versa. Event triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has its default navbar module which has vertical and horizontal classes and are manipulated with respect to the screen resolution (for mobile and small screen sizes it becomes compact/vertical).

Check this [Link](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/). Resize screen to small size

Now i want to get notified when this happens. in other word i want an event handler for this so that in code i know when this happened. is there any predefined event handling routine for it or i will there be custom code for it. 
Jquery or javascript both are fine

**Edit:**
Just adding this thing up. I am looking for a generic solution where even if the the default width value for this is not used (width: 767px).

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You can watch at the window's width property

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width() < 768){
     //do something
    } 
});
```

767px is bootstrap max-width for mobile

Comment: Yeah i thought of that. But you see this is specifying the default width of bootstrap which can be changed Sorry if i wasn't clear on that. i am more into for a generic solution for it in which whatever the width size is. Event is triggered. Thanks @shall

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an interesting question.  As the style changes to the Bootstrap navbar are done in CSS your choice is pretty limited (as opposed to having forced a style change in jQuery or in a JS function yourself.

You could theoretically put a listener to the style attribute changes using a mutation observer on the "style" attribute.  Support is pretty good these days: [CanIuse Mutation Observers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)

```
SOMEDOMITEM.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function(e){
  if (e.attrName == 'style') {
    //check how the style has changed and respond appropriately
  }
```

However, the easiest way is to confirm the horizontal width of the bootstrap breakpoint at which the navbar triggers (depends if you overrode this it triggers at 768px) and use a JS API that responds to breakpoints: [Like Enquire JS](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 767px)", {
    match : function() {
           //Do something
    },  
    unmatch : function() {
           //undo something
    }
});
```

Benefits of the latter is contrary to listening to browser width changes, your registered breakpoints are the same format as in your CSS;

Comment: both approaches make sense. But i am assuming in the second case i must know the width when i am implementing. which makes it specific. on the other hand in first approach i'd have to get the width (whatever it is) on run time and then check for cases. wouldn't that be specific too? Please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks for both tools i didn't know these existed @frank